# How to save state to url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on app in react. It is similar to google anlaytics (there is one chart, data table and few control components, that can affect chart and data table).

I want to "save state" to url. If I send the url to someone, he should see the same graph with same data as me.

It is suitable to use react router for this specific case?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very simply by storing data in the URL hash:

```
window.location.hash = 'my-state'
```

This could be an ID or a chart type. It'll be appended to the current URL. React Router supports this and other state mechanisms via "[Locations](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Custom%20Location)":

Comment: Can it be an object of key value pairs?